# How to bind a dynamic value inside a visualstate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In a Universal Windows App how to bind a value inside a visual state in XAML. For the sake of easy understanding I removed the other states except checked state under VisualStateGroups in the code below.

```
  <Page.Resources>
   <converters:UriToImageBrushConverter x:Key="cnvt"/>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyletest" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonContentForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,4,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                               
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>                             
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="29"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse" Height="23" Fill="{Binding Imgsrc, Converter={StaticResource cnvt}}" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="23">

                                </Ellipse>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckGlyph" Fill="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="13" Opacity="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="13"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" Height="29" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Width="29"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" Height="29" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Width="29"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

In the above code i tried to bind the BackgroundEllipse backgroud its not happening.

c# code:

```
private String imgsrc;

    public String Imgsrc
    {
        get
        {
            return imgsrc;
        }
        set
        {
            imgsrc = value;
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Imgsrc = "/Assets/yes.png";

    }
```

The Converter

```
class UriToImageBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Please advice me where I went wrong.

Comment: from the code above is not clear what datacontext has the radiobutton. Also check your output window when debugging to see any binding errors

Comment: Hi Liero,for easy understanding I have mentioned only checkstates, and avoided other visualstategroups(Commonstates,Focustates). I m not getting any binding error.

Comment: Is this the right way to bind string(Imgsrc) to ImageSource.

Comment: Why do you have two way binding on the ImageBrush.ImageSource?

Comment: actually twoway binding is not need, I tested in that way too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding in xaml looks for properties in DataContext by default. However, ImageBrush is not FrameworkElement and does not have DataContext.

Try this:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse"
         Fill="{Binding Imgsrc, Converter={StaticResource UriToImageBrushConverter}}" />
```

UriToImageBrushConverter is a simple class that implements IValueConverter, I'm sure you don't need me to write it.

Also make sure, that DataContext of BackgroundEllipse element is MainPage. Otherwise you could use RelativeSource:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse"
         Fill="{Binding Imgsrc, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}
                        Converter={StaticResource UriToImageSourceConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I tried as you advised too. it didn't work. I have updated the code above. And can we bind a value in resource of a page?

Comment: Have you tried both? Did you tried to set breakpoint to the UriToImageSourceConverter.Convert method to check, if it is actually called? Did you set the DataContext? The binding does not bind to properties you define on the page unless you specify the pafe as a datacontext. It must work. The problem is hidden in details you haven't shared.